# Unable to use Many Famous apps due to "Unfortunately ... Has Stopped" error

Tags: android-versions, android-device-manager, force-close, force-stop

I am unable to use any Famous Apps like - Gmail, Whatsapp, PayTM, Calendar, Antivirus apps, ram cleaner and many more apps Except few apps such as android chrome.

As soon as I am opening these apps then I am getting error "Unfortunately Whatsapp has stopped" OR "Unfortunately Gmail has stopped".

I am getting this problem from yesterday.

What I have tried:-

1) Factory reset

2) clear cache of gmail/play store/Google services.

3) Using updated version of play store/Google service/gmail/whatsapp/PayTM etc apps.

But unable to get solution till now. Anyone help me in this serious matter ?

Device details:-

Micromax canvas nitro a311, Kitkat

Comment: Mention your device and Android version by editing the question

Comment: also if you can obtain android studio from somewhere, or know someone who can use it, attach a copy of logcat if possible

Comment: Its not possible.. Looks like it can be done only on Micromax service centre.

Comment: Must be corrupted play services jar ! Logs would definitely help !